# Is there a better way in C++11 to construct classes on the stack

Tags: c++11, lambda, stack, allocation, lifetime

If I have two classes D1 and D2 that both derive from class Base, and I want to construct a particular one based on say, a boolean variable, there are various well known techniques, eg use a factory, or use smart pointers.

For example,

```
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b;
    if (flag)
    {
            b.reset(new D1());
    }
    else
    {
            b.reset(new D2());
    }
```

But this uses the heap for allocation, which is normally fine but I can think of times where it would be good to avoid the performance hit of a memory allocation.

I tried:

```
Base b = flag ? D1() : D2();      // doesn’t compile

Base& b = flag ? D1() : D2();     // doesn’t compile

Base&& b = flag ? D1() : D2();    // doesn’t compile

Base&& b = flag ? std::move(D1()) : std::move(D2());   // doesn’t compile
```

My intention is that D1 or D2 whichever is chosen is constructed on the stack, and its lifetime ends when b goes out of scope.  Intuitively, I feel there should be a way to do it.

I played with lambda functions and found that this works:

```
Base&& b = [j]()->Base&&{
                 switch (j)
                 {
                 case 0:
                       return std::move(D1());
                 default:
                       return std::move(D2());
                 }
          }();
```

Why it doesn’t suffer from the same issues as the others that do not compile I do not know.
Further, it would only be suitable for classes that are inexpensive to copy, because despite my explicit request to use move, it does I think still call a copy constructor.  But if I take away the std::move, I get a warning!

I feel this is closer to what i think should be possible but it still has some issues:

- the lambda syntax is not friendly to old-timers who havent yet
  embraced the new features of the language ( myself included)
- the copy constructor call as mentioned

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `std::move` is just a cast.  It doesn't actually move anything.  You end up getting a dangling reference.

Comment: You cant construct classes only objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are trying to do it, you are going to get a dangling reference.  Having the `std::move` is just hiding that.

Generally I just structure the code so that the logic is in a separate function.  That is, instead of

```
void f(bool flag)
{
   Base &b = // some magic to choose which derived class to instantiate

   // do something with b
}
```

I do

```
void doSomethingWith(Base &b)
{
   // do something with b
}

void f(bool flag)
{
  if (flag) {
    D1 d1;
    doSomethingWith(d1);
  }
  else {
    D2 d2;
    doSomethingWith(d2);
  }
}
```

However, if that doesn't work for you, you can use a union inside a class to help manage it:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;

struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() { }
  virtual const char* name() = 0;
};

struct Derived1 : Base {
  Derived1() { cerr << "Constructing Derived1\n"; }
  ~Derived1() { cerr << "Destructing Derived1\n"; }
  virtual const char* name() { return "Derived1"; }
};

struct Derived2 : Base {
  Derived2() { cerr << "Constructing Derived2\n"; }
  ~Derived2() { cerr << "Destructing Derived2\n"; }
  virtual const char* name() { return "Derived2"; }
};

template <typename B,typename D1,typename D2>
class Either {
  union D {
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
    D() { }
    ~D() { }
  } d;
  bool flag;

  public:
    Either(bool flag)
      : flag(flag)
    {
      if (flag) {
        new (&d.d1) D1;
      }
      else {
        new (&d.d2) D2;
      }
    }

    ~Either()
    {
      if (flag) {
        d.d1.~D1();
      }
      else {
        d.d2.~D2();
      }
    }


    B& value()
    {
      if (flag) {
        return d.d1;
      }
      else {
        return d.d2;
      }
    }
};

static void test(bool flag)
{
  Either<Base,Derived1,Derived2> either(flag);

  Base &b = either.value();

  cerr << "name=" << b.name() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
  test(true);
  test(false);
}
```

gives this output:

```
    Constructing Derived1                                                           
    name=Derived1                                                                   
    Destructing Derived1                                                            
    Constructing Derived2                                                           
    name=Derived2                                                                   
    Destructing Derived2
```

Comment: You could both keep it local *and* factor the logic into a separate function by making `doSomething` a lambda, i.e., `auto doSomething = [](Base&){ ... }; if (flag) ...`

Answer (score 5):

If you know all the types, you can use a [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/variant/), as in:

```
class Manager
{   
    using variant_type = boost::variant<Derived1, Derived2>;

    struct NameVisitor : boost::static_visitor<const char*>
    {   
        template<typename T>
        result_type operator()(T& t) const { return t.name(); }
    };  

public:
    template<typename T>
    explicit Manager(T t) : v_(std::move(t)) {}

    template<typename T>
    Manager& operator=(T t)
    { v_ = std::move(t); return *this; }

    const char* name()
    { return boost::apply_visitor(NameVisitor(), v_); }

private:
        variant_type v_; 

};
```

Note:  by using variant, you no longer need a base class or virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure you have enough space for allocating either on the stack with `std::aligned_storage`. Something like:

```
// use macros for MAX since std::max is not const-expr
std::aligned_storage<MAX(sizeof(D1), sizeof(D2)), MAX(alignof(D1), alignof(D2))> storage;
Base* b = nullptr;

if (flag)
  b = new (&storage) D1();
else
  b = new (&storage) D2();
```

You can make a wrapper type for `aligned_storage` that just takes two types and does the maximum of size/alignment of the two without needing to repeat yourself in the code using it. You can emulate `aligned_storage` for non-over-aligned types fairly trivially too if you need C++98 support. The custom type without over-aligned support would be something like:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class storage
{
  union
  {
    double d; // to force strictest alignment (on most platforms)
    char b[sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2) ? sizeof(T1) : sizeof(T2)];
  } u;
};
```

And that can be given protections against copies/moves if you so wish. It can even be turned into a simplified Boost.Variant with relatively little work.

Note that with this approach (or some of the others), **destructors will *not* be called automatically on your class and you must call them yourself**. If you want RAII patterns to apply here, you can extend the example class above to store a deleter function that is bound during construction into the space.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class storage
{
  using deleter_t = void(*)(void*);
  std::aligned_storage<
    sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2) ? sizeof(T1) : sizeof(T2),
    alignof(T1) > alignof(T2) ? alignof(T1) : alignof(T2)
  > space;
  deleter_t deleter = nullptr;
public:
  storage(const storage&) = delete;
  storage& operator=(const storage&) = delete;
  template <typename T, typename ...P>
  T* emplace(P&&... p)
  {
    destroy();
    deleter = [](void* obj){ static_cast<T*>(obj)->~T(); }
    return new (&space) T(std::forward<P>(p)...);
  }
  void destroy()
  {
    if (deleter != nullptr)
    {
      deleter(&space);
      deleter = nullptr;          
    }
  }
};

// usage:
storage<D1, D2> s;
B* b = flag ? s.emplace<D1>() : s.emplace<D2>();
```

And of course that can all be done in C++98, just with a lot more work (especially in terms of emulating the `emplace` function).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
B&&b = flag ? static_cast<B&&>(D1()) : static_cast<B&&>(D2());
```

Comment: `b` would be left as a dangling reference, since the temporary `D1` or `D2` would be destructed after that statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need them to be freed when the reference goes out of scope, you could implement another simple class (maybe named `DestructorDecorator`) that points to the object (`D1` or `D2`). And then you just have to implement `~DestructorDecorator` to call the destructor of `D1` or `D2`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned it, your `flag` is known at compile time?

As far as a compile-time flag is concerned, you can use template magic to deal with the conditional construction of the class:

First, declaring a template `create_if` which takes two types and a boolean:

```
template <typename T, typename F, bool B> struct create_if {};
```

Second, specializing `create_if` for `true` and `false` values:

```
template <typename T, typename F> struct create_if<T, F, true> { using type = T; };
template <typename T, typename F> struct create_if<T, F, false> { using type = F; };
```

Then, you can do this:

```
create_if<D1, D2, true>::type da;  // Create D1 instance
create_if<D1, D2, false>::type db; // Create D2 instance
```

You can change the boolean literals with your compile-time flag or with a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr bool foo(const int i) { return i & 1; }
create_if<D1, D2, foo(100)>::type dc; // Create D2 instance
create_if<D1, D2, foo(543)>::type dd; // Create D1 instance
```

This is valid only if the `flag` is known at compile time, I hope it helps.

[Live example](http://ideone.com/zAzgP3).